# No 'Profile Test' context menu in Visual Studio 2012 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiler, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional, then update 2, and then update 3.

In the unit test explorer, I still do not see a 'Profile Test' kind of context menu when right clicking on a test.  (Saw a number of posts saying it wasn't there, to install the available updates)

Any suggestions?  Profiling unit tests was the feature I upgraded to Professional from the Express version to get.

I have 2012 express on my machine if that might be the problem..?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find this out?  I can't see the option either

Comment: never found a solution, uninstalled 2012 pro and continue to use the free version...

Comment: I have VS Professional Update 4 and the context menu option is still missing. I can profile programs, but not unit tests.